# Imputação múltipla com dados em painel no R

Tags: r

Tenho dados em painel no seguinte formato:

```
estado ano var1 var2 var3
```

Acontece que a variável 2 (var2) não possui dados correspondentes a um dos anos.   Eu tentei realizar imputação múltipla com Amelia:

```
 out<-amelia(df,m=5,ts="ano",cs="estado",intercs=T, p2s=2,polytime = 2)
```

O problema é que o código roda indefinidamente e não aparece resultado algum. Eu já usei o código em outras ocasiões e deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Tentei replicar o problema, rodando isso aqui

```
library(dplyr)
library(Amelia)

set.seed(123)
ufs <- c("AC", "AL", "AM", "AP", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", 
         "MG", "MS", "MT", "PA", "PB", "PE", "PI", "PR", "RJ", "RN", "RO", 
         "RR", "RS", "SC", "SE", "SP", "TO")
anos <- 2000:2015
df <- expand.grid(estado = ufs, ano = anos) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = rnorm(n()), var2 = rnorm(n()), var3 = rnorm(n())) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(var1:var3), funs(ifelse(runif(n()) < .1, NA, .)))
```

(ou seja, adicionei 10% de NA's aleatoriamente em cada variável)

```
# A tibble: 432 x 5
   estado   ano        var1        var2       var3
   <fctr> <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1      AC  2000 -0.56047565  0.30003855 -0.1632849
2      AL  2000 -0.23017749 -1.00563626  2.5530261
3      AM  2000  1.55870831  0.01925927 -1.8602276
4      AP  2000  0.07050839 -1.07742065  1.1310547
5      BA  2000  0.12928774  0.71270333 -0.5272343
6      CE  2000  1.71506499  1.08477509  1.6659909
7      DF  2000  0.46091621 -2.22498770         NA
8      ES  2000 -1.26506123  1.23569346  0.1436232
9      GO  2000 -0.68685285 -1.24104450 -1.0995509
10     MA  2000 -0.44566197  0.45476927  0.9035164
# ... with 422 more rows
```

Rodei exatamente o seu código

```
out <- amelia(df,m=5,ts="ano",cs="estado",intercs=T, p2s=2,polytime=2)
```

E funcionou! Então entendo que vc deva fazer alguns sanity checks

- Verifique se `ano` é `numeric`.
- Verifique se `estado` é `factor`.
- Verifique se as demais variáveis são `numeric`.
- Verifique se as variáveis não têm NAs demais. Talvez [isso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf) ajude.

Comment: Oi Julio, obrigado. Eu refiz e, de fato,   uma das variáveis estava mal classificada. Vlw.